# Rasa - Why do I need to list intents in domain.yml?

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu

I'm trying to learn Rasa and I have a question.
Since intents are already defined in data/nlu.yml, there's a particular reason to repeat them in domain.yml? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some of Rasa's algorithms (the machine learning ones mainly) need to know which intents exist upfront. Theoretically, you could indeed argue that this can be fetched from the `nlu.yml` files. In practice, we need to remember that the `nlu.yml` files can get quite big (they also may contain non-intent data, like large lookups).

There are however a few places where the set of intents is needed, and if each lookup for this data requires checking the `nlu.yml` file it may get slow as the bot grows larger and larger.

I'm not 100% sure if this is the official reason, but I hope it's a plausible reason why it's preferable to have a central `domain.yml` file that contains all settings without containing the data as well.

Comment: I see your point and it's quite clear. I'm just wondering if the nlu.yml file could be parsed just once to collect all the intents for later use.